# Variable was not declared in scope

Tags: c++

All of the variables declared in `int` main does not work in `int` pickword. It just says "`variable not declared in this scope`". This problem goes away when I declare all the variables before `int` main. But I'm trying to avoid using global variables, but the static word isn't doing anything

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
pickword();

int main()
{
    static struct word
    {
        string indefSing;
        string defSing;
        string indefPlural;
        string defPlural;
    };
    static word aeble = {"aeble", "aeblet", "aebler", "aeblerne"};
    static word bog = {"bog", "bogen", "boger", "bogerne"};
    static word hund = {"hund", "hunden", "hunde", "hundene"};
    static string promptform;
    static string wordform;
    static word rightword;

    void pickword();

    cout << "Decline the word " << rightword.indefSing << "in the " << promptform << endl;

    return 0;
}

void pickword()
{
    cout << "welcome to mr jiggys plural practice for danish" << endl;

    pickword();
    using namespace std;

    srand(time(0));
    int wordnumber = rand()% 3;
    switch (wordnumber) //picks the word to change
    {
    case 0:
        rightword = aeble;
        break;
    case 1:
        rightword = bog;
        break;
    case 2:
        rightword = hund;
        break;
    };

    int wordformnumber = rand()% 3;
    switch (wordformnumber) //decides which form of the word to use
    {
    case 0:
        wordform = rightword.defSing;
        promptform = "definite singular";
    case 1:
        wordform = rightword.indefPlural;
        promptform = "indefinite plural";
    case 2:
        wordform = rightword.defPlural;
        promptform = "indefinite Plural";
    };
}
```

Comment: unrelated: the infinite recursion of `pickword()` is a train wreck in the making. I hope you like that welcome message, because you're about to see a *lot* of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass those variables to pickword because all variables declared inside  main function don't share scope with pickword function. Each function has it's own scope. So you cannot access variables declared in main functions in pickword function just by merely calling it. So either declare your variables outside the main function so that they can be accessed by other functions or simply pass them as parameters to the functions in which you need to access them.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared some variables in main ( i.e local variables ). How could pickword know about these local variabes.

You have two options here depending whether you want pickword to change states of your variables declared in main OR not.

1) Pass by value.

```
int main ()
{
int x ;
pickword (x); 
}
pickword ( int x );   //Pickword can't change value of x.
```

2) Pass by reference:-

```
int main()
{
int x ;
pickword (x); 
}
pickword(int& x);  //Pickword can change value of x.
```